# Find only particular days between two dates

Tags: oracle, date, date-math

I have an Oracle table with data like below:

```
 1. ID           DATE 
 2. 12           02/11/2013
 3. 12           02/12/2013
 4. 13           02/11/2013
 5. 13           02/12/2013
 6. 13           02/13/2013
 7. 13           02/14/2013
 8. 14           02/11/2013
 9. 14           02/12/2013
10. 14           02/13/2013
```

I need to find only those ID who has only Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday dates, so here only ID = 14 should be returned. I am using Oracle and dates are in format MM/DD/YYYY.
Please advice.

Regards,
Nitin

Comment: Are you dates real dates (by datatype) or are they strings in the format MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: When dealing with SQL it usually helps if you give us some code to create the table you're having instead of an ASCII table dump.

Answer (score 4):

If date column is DATE datatype, then you can

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case 
           when to_char(date_col,'fmday') 
                in ('monday','tuesday','wednesday') then 1
           else 99
           end) = 3;
```

**EDIT**: *Corected the above code at the igr's observation*

But this is ok only if you don't have a day twice for the same id.

If the column is varchar2 then the condition becomes `to_char(to_date(your_col,'mm/dd/yyyy'),'fmday') in ...`

A more robust code would be:

```
select id 
from(
    select id, date_col
    from your_table
    group by id, date_col
)
group by id
having sum(case 
           when to_char(date_col,'fmday', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') 
                    in ('monday','tuesday','wednesday') then 1
           else 99
           end) = 3;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution depend on the language settings you are working with?

Comment: This is not important and is not the problem of user. He wants only to know how to select the ids with that property.

Comment: Unfortunately the settings between systems will differ. So if there is a solution that does not depend on those settings use that. Always.

Comment: Your examples do not eliminate id=13

Comment: @igr id-12 have two days. Can't have count(*) = 3.

Comment: @igr you are right now, i'll change de code. Your code is ok.

Comment: @FlorinGhita you need to add the mask as `fmday` and not `day` otherwise monday/tueday get blank padded and thus never match your in clauses, or just use `dy` with `mon` `tue` etc..

Answer (score 1):

do something like

```
SELECT * FROM your_table t 
      where to_char(t.DATE, 'DY') in ('whatever_day_abbreviation_day_you_use');
```

alternatively if you prefer you could use day numbers like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table t 
     where  to_number(to_char(d.ts, 'D')) in (1,2,3);
```

if you'd like to avoid ID repetition add DISTINCTION

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM your_table t 
     where  to_number(to_char(d.ts, 'D')) in (1,2,3);
```

Comment: these will return also the id: 12, 13

Comment: your condition is "... has only Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday dates"; well 2/11 and 2/12 ARE Monday and Tuesday...

Comment: Is the OP condition, not mine. Read his requirement again. He wants the ids wich have those three days and only three. Not just two and not anonther different day.

Comment: Also, the value of D is dependent on NLS_TERRITORY setting.  In many places 1 is not Monday, it is Sunday or Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
from (
  select 
     id, 
     sum (case when to_char(dt, 'D', 'nls_territory=AMERICA') between 1 and 3 then 1 else -1 end) AS cnt
  from t
  group by id
)
where cnt=3
```

NOTE: I assumed (id,dt) is unique - no two lines with same id and date.

Comment: It is ok as far as Monday is first day of week. This depends on nls_territory.

Comment: @igr, you also need a `group by id` in the inner select

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions - I did a change.